# What are the types of datatypes in informatica and range of values they can take

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I was trying to load data into db using informatica, where i used function to_integer() but it threw error that interger overlow.
I need to load data into a column of precision 18,0 in SQL
Can someone please tell different data types available in which i can convert string into number and load in db for values of high range

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is documented in the Informatica manual

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Transformation Datatypes in Informatica Help pages. For your case, TO_BIGINT should solve the problem. BIGINT supports 19 digits.

[image]